# Edit error message in woocommerce cart page

Tags: woocommerce

I want to edit the following message displayed by woocommerce in the checkout area

" No shipping methods were found; please recalculate your shipping or continue to checkout and enter your full address to see if there is shipping available to your location"

The message appears if the buyer is not from an approved country, I want a message that says "for a shipping quote email (email address)"

Could you tell me/how where this is done please.

ATB
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file "cart-shipping" in /plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/

The text to edit is around line 72 (Woocommerce Version 2.2.8)

Edit the echo'd html/text between the `<p>' . __( '` and `' ) . '</p>`

(In other words, you can add html elements inside an echo statement.)